# Solutions of the functional equation $f(x) + f(qx) = 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-equations

How can I find the solutions of 
$$f(x) + f(qx) = 0,$$ where $q \in \mathbb{Q}, q\neq1, x \in \mathbb{R}$, with $f$ being a continuous function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's let $x_0$ be an arbitrary real number.

For $|q| < 1$, we find that by substituting $x=x_0$ that

$$f(x_0) = -f(qx_0)$$
and, substituting $x=qx_0$,
$$f(q^2x_0) = -f(qx_0)$$
Thus,
$f(x_0) = f(x_0q^2)$, or more generally
$$f(x_0) = f(x_0q^{2n})$$

Now, $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_0q^{2n} = 0$, so by continuity,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_0q^{2n}) = f(\lim_{n\to\infty}xq^{2n}) = f(0)$$
But, on the other hand $f(x_0q^{2n} = f(x_0)$ for all $n$, so
$$f(x_0) = \lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_0q^{2n}) =  f(0)$$
By substituting $x = 0$ into the function equation, we find
$2f(0) = 0$, so
$$f(x_0) = f(0) = 0$$
and $f$ is the zero function.
Now, let's suppose $|q| > 1$.  Then, if we substitute $x = \frac{y}{q}$, we find
$$f(\frac{1}{q}y) + f(y) = 0$$
and since $\left|\frac{1}{q}\right| < 1$, we can use the previous argument to show that $f \equiv 0$.

---

The 'interesting' case is $q = -1$.  Then, we can rearrange to find
$$f(x) = -f(-x)$$
so any continuous odd function (for example, $f(x) = x$ or $f(x) = \sin x$) is a solution.

Comment: By continuity, $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(xq^{2n}) = f(\lim_{n\to\infty}xq^{2n}) = f(0)$.  Where do you need more details?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I actually would appreciate a complete explanation: this is my first functional equation and I don't really know what to do.

Comment: @user62029 OK, I've given a complete answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. As I said in another comment I now understand this solution, but I still don't see how I should have thought of this myself. Could you recommend some material (for example, lecture notes available online) that teaches how to go about solving a functional equation?